# 複数のString型からDate型への変換

Tags: android, java

String型からDate型の変換は、基本は次のように出来ることはわかります

```
String dateStr = "20140101 00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
Date formatDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

これは、Date型に変えたい文字列の型が１つに定まっているからできる事だと思います。
取得するStringの日付形式が複数ある場合にはどのように処理するのでしょうか？

これが数種類であると確定しているなら、その種類に併せて分岐させればよいと思います。
が、複数ある場合に日付フォーマットとして一般的なものであれば、放り込めばDate型に変換してくれる関数のようなものはないのでしょうか？

例えば以下のような日付をString型で取得します。

```
2016-01-08T15:35:42Z
2016-01-03T13:18:06.483+09:00
Sat, 31 Oct 2015 13:33:51 +0000
```

Comment: See [How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtilsのparseDate()メソッドで可能です。

```
final String[] PATTERN = {"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSZ",
                    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"};
String data1 = "2016-01-08T15:35:42Z";
String data2 = "2016-01-03T13:18:06.483+09:00";
String data3 = "Sat, 31 Oct 2015 13:33:51 +0000";

System.out.println(DateUtils.parseDate(date1, PATTERN));
System.out.println(DateUtils.parseDate(date2, PATTERN));
System.out.println(DateUtils.parseDate(date3, PATTERN));
```

Date関連のライブラリなんか使えばほかにも方法があると思いますが、
おそらく一番使われているのではないでしょうか。
ちなみに、英語の月名の変換は、それぞれのUtilityで変換できるもの、できないものがあるのに注意してください。

Comment: Android Studioを使っているとして、build.gradle の dependencies 以下に 例えば `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'` を追加すれば、Apache Commons ライブラリをすぐ使えます。

Answer (score 2):

omarun さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/20831/4959)は汎用性があると思いますが、外部ライブラリであるApache Commonsに依存しないAndroid SDKオンリーの実装として以下が使えます：

```
final String[] formatStrings = {"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
                          "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSZ",
                          "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"}

Date tryParse(String dateString) {
    for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(dateString);
        }
        catch (ParseException ignore) {}
    }
    return null;
}
```

出典: [How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024604/328640)